# Configuring DisplayTag for individual pages

Tags: configuration, struts2, displaytag

I have too many modules (around 90) in my project.
But I want to keep individual displaytag.properties file for each module rather than having single file for whole project.

How to achieve this.

I am using struts2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can configure each displaytag using the appropiate bundle, remember the bundle search order from S2 [docs](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/localization.html):

- ActionClass.properties Interface.properties
- Interface.properties (every interface and sub-interface)
- BaseClass.properties (all the way to Object.properties)
- ModelDriven's model (if implements ModelDriven), for the model object repeat from 1
- package.properties (of the directory where class is located and every parent directory all the way to the root directory)
- search up the i18n message key hierarchy itself
- global resource properties

and from the docs for the DisplayTag library:

> For the whole web application, create a custom properties file named "displaytag.properties" and place it in the application classpath. Displaytag will use the locale of the request object to determine the locale of the property file to use; if the key required does not exist in the specified file, the key will be loaded from a more general property file.

so i guess that the displaytag will search the config keys in the s2 available bundles.